# Technique to detect if a field or member getter is a primary key

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am implementing an optimization to an algorithm.

The optimization consists in stopping the search immediately when the *value of a field* in a struct is known to be unique. To get the point, just imagine that my struct is like a database table and the field with the unique value would be the equivalent of a "primary key" in a relation database.

I want to dispatch to an implementatio that stops eagerly when it finds the first occurrence of a value if I know that the value of that field is unique. I know this at compile-time by design.

So I want to detect that a given field value is unique at compile-time.

My function looks like this:

```
template <class Storage, class Getter, class Value>
vector<MyStruct> select_records(Storage const & s, Getter g, Value const & v);
```

This function will dispatch:

- if Getter, which is a member pointer to data, is a "primary key", then it will dispatch to the optimized implementation.
- otherwise, dispatch to the implementation that traverses all the Storage.

How could I achieve "primary key" detection? Constraint: The solution must be non-intrusive.

Comment: How do you *define* a primary key?

Comment: Well, one field of a struct that I know its value will be unique, that's all you need.

Comment: No, that's *not* all we need. The question is unclear to the poibnt of being unasnwerable as it is now. What does "unique" mean? Its value is unique ... among what? Or is something else about it that's unique (its name)? Can different instances of the same struct type have a different field as primary key? You need to add *way* more information (ideally a pseudo-code example) to make this question answerable.

Comment: It seems that you have invented bunch of terms and use these and we have no idea what you are talking about unless you post some code.

Comment: I edited the question. Does it look clear now?

Comment: Another edit. I start to think that it is at least understandable.

Comment: The compiler knows types, and values of integral template parameters. How should it somehow know at compile time what's in your database?

Comment: @davidhigh his definition of primary key has nothing to do with a database :D

Comment: @deW1: however I understand it like this: "So I want to detect that a given field value is unique at compile-time". The compiler can't do this unless it holds all required values.

Comment: Well, I am not sticking to the formal definition of a database. But the point is, or maybe I studied something else, I don't know... that a relational database PRIMARY KEY from a table is unique, always. I think that is enough to understand the rest of the explanation. I don't know the values of my structs, what I DO know is that there is a certain field that no two struct instances will ever have, because they are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've given, there is no way to do what you want at compile time. `Getter` is only a type, and you said you cannot identify a primary key by type alone. Which means you're not doing the identification based on `Getter` (the type), but based on `g`, which is a *runtime* value. There is of course no compile-time access to a runtime value.

If possible, you could achieve this by turning `g` into a compile-time piece of information, something like this:

```
template <class Storage, class Value, Value Storage::*getter>
vector<MyStruct> select_records(Storage const & s, Value const & v);
```

And then specialise it for the known values of `getter` which correspond to the primary key.

---

Of course, the above requires you to specify all template arguments explicitly (because the one you want to specify as such, `getter`, is last), and doesn't really play nice because function templates cannot be partially specialised. Here's something that offers somewhat better syntax and specialisation options:

```
template <class Storage, class Value>
Selector<Storage, Value> record_selector(Storage const & s, Value const & v)
{
  return Selector<Storage, Value>(s, v);
}


template <class Storage, class Value>
class Selector
{
  Storage const & s;
  Value const & v;

public:
  Selector(Storage const & s, Value const & v) : s(s), v(v) {}

  template <Value Storage::*getter>
  vector<MyStruct> select()
  {
    return Select_Impl<Storage, Value, getter, IsPrimaryKey<Storage, Value, getter>::value>::call(s, v);
  }
};


template <class Storage, class Value, Value Storage::*getter, bool primary>
struct Select_Impl
{
  static vector<MyStruct> call(Storage const & s, Value const & v)
  {
    // Normal implementation.
  }
};


template <class Storage, class Value, Value Storage::*getter>
struct Select_Impl<Storage, Value, getter, true>
{
  static vector<MyStruct> call(Storage const & s, Value const & v)
  {
    // Optimised implementation
  }
};


template <class Storage, class Value, Value Storage::*getter>
struct IsPrimaryKey
{
  static const bool value = false;
};
// Specialise the above for each primary key with `value` set to `true`
// This should be possible, since you said you know the set of primary keys at compile-time
```

In code, you should then be able to use it like this:

```
vector<MyStruct> res = record_selector(s, v).select<&SomeStorage::someMember>();
```